# How to handle Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I have an ArticleController with the following code :

```
def edit
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
end
```

And the following test:

```
describe "GET 'edit'" do
  it "should fail when signed in and editing another user article" do
    sign_in @user
    get :edit, :id => @another_user_article.id
    response.should_not be_success
  end
end
```

However, when I start the test, I get the following error (which is normal), but I wonder how to handle that so my test can pass?

```
Failure/Error: get :edit, :id => @another_user_article.id
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:
   Document not found for class Article with id(s) 4f9e71be4adfdcc02300001d.
```

I thought about changing my controller method by this one, but that does not seems right to me :

```
def edit
  @article = Article.first(conditions: { _id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id })
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either decide that the right thing for your code to do in this circumstance is to raise an exception, so change your spec to

```
expect { get :edit, :id => @another_user_article.id}.to raise_error(Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound)
```

or you can decide that what your controller should do in this case is explicitly render a 404: rescue the exception at the controller level (either in the action or via `rescue_from`), in which case your spec should pass as is.

Comment: The `expect { ... }.to raise_error`part is exactly what I was lacking. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should add that I was breaking my head against this, until I found using `expect(something)` won't work. It has to be inside a proc.

Answer (score 0):

Here you didnt created the object @another_user_article. First load fixtures for another_user_article model, then create this object in before part of scenario.

Comment: The object is already created, but I'm trying to load it with a different user. As I clearly stated in the question, my problem is how to handle that error in the tests.